Is it possible to establish BGP sessions to the same neighbor IP using different source IPs?
I am using FRR to create two sessions to the same neighbor IP but using different source IPs, e.g. create a session with the neighbor 192.168.0.1 from 192.168.0.2 and 192.168.0.3.
Is it possible to establish BGP sessions to the same neighbor IP using different source IPs and a single FRR BGP server?
